# Python is already installed within virtual env

Tags: python, django, virtual-environment

When I created a virtual Environment , in that I am already getting Python 3.7 which is on my local Machine . But I need Python 2 for my Project . How should I install that in my virtualenv And Also why python is already there?

Comment: You need to specify what version of Python you want to use. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1534343/4690525

Comment: Be careful in use Python 2, the retire is coming ... https://pythonclock.org/